# python requests downloading incorrect sound file from Google Translate

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, google-translate

I'm using the script below to download the Chinese 老師, but when I run it, I get a file different from the one present at that URL. I think this an encoding issue, but as I've specified UTF-8, I'm not sure what's happening.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-CN&q=老師"

r = requests.get(url)

with open('test.mp3', 'wb') as test:
    test.write(r.content)
```

UPDATE:

As per @abarnert's suggestion, I've checked that the file is UTF-8 with BOM and tested the code with 'idna'.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

url_1 = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-CN&q=老師"
url_2 = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-CN&q=\u8001\u5e2b"

r_1 = requests.get(url_1)
r_1_b = requests.get(url_1.encode('idna'))
r_2 = requests.get(url_2)
r_2_b = requests.get(url_2.encode('idna'))

# This downloads nonsense:
with open('r_1.mp3', 'wb') as test:
    test.write(r_1.content)

# This throws the error specified at bottom:
with open('r_1_b.mp3', 'wb') as test:
    test.write(r_1_b.content)

# This parses the characters individually, producing
# a file consisting of "u, eight, zero..." in Mandarin
with open('r_2.mp3', 'wb') as test:
    test.write(r_2.content)

# This produces a sound file consisting of "u, eight, zero, zero..." in Mandarin
with open('r_2_b.mp3', 'wb') as test:
    test.write(r_2_b.content)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MZ/Desktop/tts3.py", line 12, in <module>
    r_1_b = requests.get(url_1.encode('idna'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/idna.py", line 164, in encode
    result.append(ToASCII(label))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/idna.py", line 76, in ToASCII
    label = nameprep(label)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/idna.py", line 21, in nameprep
    newlabel.append(stringprep.map_table_b2(c))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/stringprep.py", line 197, in map_table_b2
    b = unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", al)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
[Finished in 15.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Where have you specified UTF-8? Not in your code, your URL, your source file encoding, or anything else I can see.

Comment: Also, is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the header. I have tried it in 2 and 3.

Comment: OK, first, are you sure your text editor agrees that this is UTF-8? Can you try it with `\u8001\u5e2b` instead of `老師`? And second, I'm sure requests knows how to do IDNA encoding, but just to rule it out, can you try `requests.get(url.encode('idna'))`?

Comment: Please see my update to the question. Thanks

Comment: In Python 2.x, you need to use `url_1 = u"…"` and likewise for `url_2` for this test to make any sense. (In 3.x, that shouldn't be necessary, but it's harmless.) Anyway, you've got enough here that I can test this myself, so let me do so rather than trying to guide you through the tests (unless I can't reproduce the problem).

Comment: Meanwhile, forget the IDNA thing; that was me being stupid. It should obviously be URL-encoding the query string, not IDNA-encoding it.

Comment: As a side note, your file really shouldn't be "UTF-8 with BOM"; that's only marginally tolerated by the standard, and a lot of software won't work with it. (Except on Windows, where a lot of software absolutely loves it.) But I suppose it is a good way to enforce and verify that this really is UTF-8, for a test like this. And it definitely shouldn't affect the test.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to reproduce your problem in Python 2 on both Linux and Windows (although the nonsense I get is different on each). But I can't reproduce it in Python 3, and I don't think you actually did either.

The short version is: you *always* want to use Unicode string literals if you want to include non-ASCII characters. On Python 2, that means a `u` prefix (on Python 3, the `u` prefix is meaningless but harmless):

```
url = u"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-CN&q=老師"
```

And the safest thing to do (because then the wrong encoding in your text editor or your coding declaration can't affect anything) is:

```
url_2 = u"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-CN&q=\u8001\u5e2b"
```

Without that, you're passing a bunch of UTF-8 bytes to `requests` without telling it that they're UTF-8.

What I'd expect it to do in that case is look at `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which will probably be 'ascii' at least on Mac and Linux, try to decode with that, and get an exception. On Windows, it might be 'cp1252' or 'big5' or whatever your system setting is, so it might send mojibake.

But it's not actually doing that. I'm not sure *what* it's doing, but it correctly guesses UTF-8 on Mac, does something bizarre that results in "eh eh eh" in three different tones on Linux (I think it's just interpreting the bytes as the equivalent codepoints, so `老` turns into U+00E8, U+0080, U+0081?), and something different and bizarre that starts with the same first syllable but then has different ones on Windows.

For `url_2`, it's a little simpler: in 2.x non-Unicode string literals, `\u8001` isn't considered an escape sequence, it's just the six characters backslash, `u`, `8`, `0`, 0`,`1`. Which`requests` will dutifully send to Google, which it'll translate and send back to you as someone reading out those characters.

If you add the `u` prefix, however, both of them work.

And in Python 3, with or without the `u` prefix, both of them work. (Interestingly, in 3.x, it works even with a `b` prefix… but apparently only because it just always assumes bytes are UTF-8 in 3.x; if I give it Big5 bytes, it mojibakes them as UTF-8 even if my `sys.getdefaultencoding` is right.)

Also, manually query-string-encoding the query works, but that isn't necessary, and doesn't make any difference.